# Is it necessary to call rand.Seed manually?

Tags: go, random

I want to know do we have to call `rand.Seed(n)` manually in Go?
I have a code that looks like this:

```golang
import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(rand.Intn(100))
    fmt.Println(rand.Intn(100))
    fmt.Println(rand.Intn(100))
}
```

Everytime I run this code, each line prints different numbers than the others.
So do I need to call `rand.Seed(n)` each time before calling `rand.Intn(100)`?

Comment: No, it's not necessary. See the doc at https://pkg.go.dev/math/rand@go1.20.6#Seed to see what `rand.Seed` actually does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Prior to Go 1.20, the global, shared Source was seeded to 1 internally, so each run of the appliation would produce the same pseudo-random sequences.

Calling [`rand.Seed()`](https://pkg.go.dev/math/rand#Seed) **is not needed starting from Go 1.20**. [Release notes](https://go.dev/doc/go1.20):

> **The `math/rand` package now automatically seeds the global random number generator (used by top-level functions like `Float64` and `Int`) with a random value, and the top-level `Seed` function has been deprecated.** Programs that need a reproducible sequence of random numbers should prefer to allocate their own random source, using `rand.New(rand.NewSource(seed))`.
>
> Programs that need the earlier consistent global seeding behavior can set `GODEBUG=randautoseed=0` in their environment.
>
> The top-level `Read` function has been deprecated. In almost all cases, `crypto/rand.Read` is more appropriate.

`rand.Seed()` also has this DEPRICATION in its doc:

> Deprecated: Programs that call Seed and then expect a specific sequence of results from the global random source (using functions such as Int) can be broken when a dependency changes how much it consumes from the global random source. To avoid such breakages, programs that need a specific result sequence should use NewRand(NewSource(seed)) to obtain a random generator that other packages cannot access.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a Source:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
)

func main() {
    wdRand := rand.New(rand.NewSource(42))
    fmt.Println(wdRand.Intn(100))
    fmt.Println(wdRand.Intn(100))
    fmt.Println(wdRand.Intn(100))
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/Sp0Wfx0Bkbb

Now everytime you call the code, the results become identical.